# UICollectionView's delegate should conform to CHTCollectionViewDelegateWaterfallLayout protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, delegates, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm using a view controller with UITabbar inside and insert a subview which has [CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout](https://github.com/lonelyplanet/TE-CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout/blob/master/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout.m), but I got the runtime error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView's delegate should conform to CHTCollectionViewDelegateWaterfallLayout protocol'

I was declare the **CHTCollectionViewDelegateWaterfallLayout** already and implement it's required method

How to solve it, any solution?

My first view controller code here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self.myTabbar setAlpha:0.95];  

self.myTabbar.delegate = self;  

UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.view insertSubview:[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tab1"].view belowSubview:self.myTabbar];
[self.myTabbar setSelectedItem:self.myTabbar.items[0]];
self.currentItem = [self.myTabbar selectedItem];}
```

and here's the view controller that have collection view .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, CHTCollectionViewDelegateWaterfallLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionViewController;
@end
```

and the delegate's required method in .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.collectionViewController.prefetchDataSource = self;
self.collectionViewController.dataSource = self;
self.collectionViewController.delegate = self;
}
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.item % 2 == 1) {
    CGFloat cellWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width /2.2;
    CGFloat cellHeight = cellWidth * 1.6;
    return CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellHeight);
} else {
    CGFloat cellWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width /2.2;
    CGFloat cellHeight = cellWidth * 2;
    return CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellHeight);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove registering of `<UICollectionViewDelegate>` from `MainViewController`. Your `MainViewController` interface should look like this -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, CHTCollectionViewDelegateWaterfallLayout, UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionViewController;
@end
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem still happen even I register  **UICollectionViewDelegate** or not.
When I run **MainViewController** as initial view, it's was normal. But when I run from my **first view** , this issue happen after the **- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath** method done, in stack it right after **-[CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout prepareLayout]**